# How to slice images in gimp?

Tags: gimp

I need to slice tool in gimp to create tables on an image and eventually hyperlink the table cell. I need it in order to make a table on image, to be send as a visual email. I don't want to use image map (as I've heard it is not compatible with all devices) and  I missed the functionally of selecting certain area and assign a table to it in gimp, like one can do in Photoshop . I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this help? http://gimp4you.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/guillotine-the-gimp-way-to-slice-images/

Comment: No. because Guillotine does not create a code to re-create the image like the “Slice” filter.

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of GIMP have the [Slice filter](http://docs.gimp.org/en/python-fu-slice.html), this should come close to the intended result.